# How can you set a window.onload event that fires when all dynamically added iframes are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I want to set one `window.onload` event. I want to dynamically add `iframes` to the page. Each time an iframe is loaded, I want the window.onload to fire. How can I do that?

Edit: Say I add the 5th `iframe`. I want to run a function only if `iframes` 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are all loaded. I can't just add handlers to each `iframe` because what if `iframe` 5 finishes loading before `iframe` 2?

*The following doesn't work:*

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emzbZj?editors=101

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>add</button>
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>').insertAfter('button');
  });
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    console.log('loaded'); // doesn't fire when dynamically added iframes load
  });
});
```

Comment: `iframe` has it's own `window`, you want that load event. `$('iframe').on('load...'`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, I hope this fiddle works as you expect it

http://jsfiddle.net/sahilbatla/4wbpbjbo/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
      $('<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>').on('load',function() {
        alert('loaded')
      }).insertAfter('button');
  });
});
```

Comment: See my comment to the other answer. I'll update the question to explain.

Comment: I might be wrong, but that code will not wait for a frame that takes longer to load, will it?

Comment: It will silently fail it now, if you want to load 5 once first four are finished loading, just add a setTimeout to the else part of the if statement, in loadEvent handler, if thats what you need. - http://jsfiddle.net/sahilbatla/4wbpbjbo/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the iframe's load event.
This should work:

```
function loaded(){
  console.log('loaded');
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var iframe = $('<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>');
  iframe.insertAfter('button');
  iframe.load(function(){
    loaded();
  });
});

$(window).on('load', function() {
  loaded();
});
```

**Update**:

I you want to wait for the other frames to have loaded first (as per your edit), you can do this:

```
var queue = [];

function loaded(){
  console.log(queue);
  console.log("Loaded");
}

function updateQueue(){
  var frameNo = $("iframe").length;
  queue.push(frameNo);
  processLoadEvent(frameNo); 
}

function processLoadEvent(frameNo){
  if (queue.length === frameNo){
    loaded();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){ processLoadEvent(frameNo); }, 500);
  }
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var iframe = $('<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>');
  iframe.insertAfter('button');
  iframe.load(function(){
    updateQueue();
  });
});

// Your initial iframe
$("iframe").on("load", updateQueue);
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/Lvr2ofgw/).

Comment: What about checking to see if all `iframes` on the page are loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The above code will execute whatever is in the `loaded()` function for each iframe that is inserted dynamically. You can't really "check" that an iframe is loaded, you can however, execute some code once it has.

Comment: Say I add the 5th `iframe`. I want to run a function only if `iframes` 1,2,3,4 and 5 are all loaded. Your code just hooks up a handler to each `iframe`. What if `iframe` 5 finishes loading before `iframe` 2? In that case your code would run, but I wouldn't want it to.

Comment: Do you want it to then fail silently, or do you want all of the callbacks to execute in turn?

Comment: If `iframe` 5 finishes loading before `iframe` 2, I just want it to wait until `iframe` 2 loads, and then run a function.

Comment: I updated my answer. Slightly more verbose than sahilbathla's, but hey.